# Is there a Sage function for finding the length of a matrix?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, matrix, jupyter-notebook, sage

I have a matrix (in Sage) in a notebook - through Jupyter.

How do I find the size of this matrix in Sage?
I know in Python I can find the length of a list with

```
len(list)
```

Is there, in Sage, a function that does this, but with a matrix?
Kinda like

```
len(matrix)
```

#### Example when I try it:

```
len([1, 2, 3])
3

len(matrix([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]))
TypeError: object of type sage.matrix.matrix_integer_dense.Matrix_integer_dense' has no len()
```

#### Same with:

```
aMatrix = matrix([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
aMatrix
len(aMatrix)
```

Thanks! Appreciate any help.

Comment: Thanks for the help; again - Really appreciating it. //Have a great weekend on both you - and Future readers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the methods

- `nrows` for the number of rows
- `ncols` for the number of columns
- `dimensions` for both at once

Example:

```
sage: a = matrix([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
sage: a
[1 2 3]
[4 5 6]

sage: a.nrows()
2
sage: a.ncols()
3
sage: a.dimensions()
(2, 3)
```

To get the number of elements:

```
sage: a.nrows() * a.ncols()
6
sage: prod(a.dimensions())
6
```

Other variations:

```
sage: len(list(a))
2
sage: len(list(a.T))
3
sage: len(a.list())
6
```

Explanation:

- `list(a)` gives the list of rows (as vectors)
- `a.T` is the transpose matrix
- `a.list()` gives the list of entries
- `a.dense_coefficient_list()` also gives that
- `a.coefficients()` gives a list of nonzero entries

Details:

```
sage: list(a)
[(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)]
sage: a.T
[1 4]
[2 5]
[3 6]
sage: a.list()
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

More possibilities:

```
sage: sum(1 for row in a for entry in row)
6
sage: sum(1 for _ in a.list())
6
```

Comment: This was a brilliant answer!  Many thanks! Extremely Pythonic too! :)